# Min password length error server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, password-management

I need to set up a couple of users on our domain but they need to have 6 character passwords (apparently using 7 would be just too much hassle and unfortunately due to their positions its not a battle the IT dept are going to win)

We are using server 2012 for our DC

each time I try to set a password I get the 0x800708c5 error.

I have set the password policy to have the following parameters

Enforce Password History - 3 passwords remembered
Max password age - 42 days
Min password age - 0 days
Min password length - 6 characters
password must meet complex req ... - disabled

after setting these i ran a gpupdate /force command to update

its still not letting me set a 6 character password, each time im getting the same error code.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Open the local group policy editor and verify the policy has been pushed to the client.

Comment: @Ramhound so the policy in here was different, except for the 6 character length setting that was already in place, please excuse this noobish question but how can I force these settings through to the client?

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator The client machine hasnt joined the domain yet, the only place I am attempting to set the password from is the AD this is where I get the error.

Comment: @ModeratorImpersonator so... I have just logged onto a client machine as one of the users, changed the password and it has gone through straight away. for some reason on a machine its fine but AD is throwing errors for god knows what reason.

Comment: Okay, well check the `Default Domain` GP and put a screen shot up of your settings I suppose as that error should indicate the password does NOT meet the requirements the GP has in place. You might disable the policy, `gpupdate /force`, see if it lets you set the password, and then re-enable it, etc. and `gpupdate /force` again for a potential workaround. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: If you are trying to set the password complexity settings in another GPO than `Default Domain`, then the `Default Domain` setting may also be set and take precedence over the other GPO settings you have set so just check and be sure you have that setup correctly.

Comment: @Boneyt - You can apply a specific policy to specific machines on the domain.